# Puppet server not starting

Tags: puppet, puppet-foreman

need help on small issue -

Puppet server :

```
# puppet --version
6.15.0

puppetserver --version
puppetserver version: 6.11.0




openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

Status :

```
systemctl status puppetserver.service

puppetserver.service - puppetserver Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Thu 2020-05-07 15:08:50 PDT; 8s ago
  Control: 28858 (bash)
    Tasks: 33 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puppetserver.service
           ├─28858 bash /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/cli/apps/start
           ├─28865 /usr/bin/java -Xms2G -Xmx4G -Djruby.logger.class=com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.jruby.Slf4jLogger -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar:/opt/puppe...
           └─28915 sleep 1
```

May 07 15:08:50 xxxx systemd[1]: Starting puppetserver Service...

Log :

/var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver

```
..
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RuntimeError: (Error) Cannot determine basic system flavour

..
2020-05-07T15:10:10.774-07:00 ERROR [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.internal] Error during service init!!!

..
Caused by: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (Error) Cannot determine basic system flavour
```

It was working just fine for few hr

Tried service bounce

tried ( in /etc/sysconfig/puppetserver ) - giving more memory

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Xms2G -Xmx4G -Djruby.logger.class=com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.jruby.Slf4jLogger"
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

turned out the temp dir parameter in below files was somehow got removed ie "-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/puppetlabs/temp"

grep -i temp /etc/sysconfig/puppetserver
JAVA_ARGS="-Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djruby.logger.class=com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.jruby.Slf4jLogger -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/puppetlabs/temp"

re-added

-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/puppetlabs/temp" to above file & restarted

https://puppet.com/docs/puppetserver/latest/known_issues.html#tmp-directory-mounted-noexec